# Theorem deduction using Orthonormal Projections Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthonormal, orthogonal-matrices, projection-matrices

**Theorem**: ${x_1,x_2, ... ,x_k}$ be an orthonormal basis of $S$. Then for any $x \in V$, $y$ defined as
$$y = \sum_{i=1}^k \langle x, x_i\rangle x_i$$
is the orthogonal projection of $x$ into S and $x - y$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ into $S^\perp$.

**Question**: Deduce above theorem by the fact that $P_A = AA^T$ if the columns of
$A$ form an orthonormal set where $P_A$ is the orthogonal projection matrix.

Answer (score 0):

In fact,
\begin{eqnarray}
P_Ax&=&AA^Tx\\
&=&(x_1,\cdots,x_k)\left(\begin{matrix}x_1^T\\\cdots\\x_k^T\end{matrix}\right)x\\
&=&\sum_{i=1}^k(x_ix_i^T)x\\
&=&\sum_{i=1}^kx_i(x_i^Tx)\\
&=&\sum_{i=1}^k(x^Tx_i)x_i\\
&=&\sum_{i=1}^k\left<x,x_i\right>x_i.
\end{eqnarray}